# Google Maps v3: How can I reliably I retrieve Icon size and anchor position?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am porting a library from v2 to v3.  Developers can use whatever custom icons they want for their markers, however, I need to be able to get the size of the icon and the anchor position for the icon.  Using v2, gmaps library would calculate all of that and make it available. With v3, when you retrieve an Icon from the marker, it could be a string with just the URL of the image.  Or, it can be a MarkerImage that contains only as much information as the developer provided in the constructor. Using v3, how can I reliably get the icon size and anchor position of a marker icon?

```
// v2 way
var markerImage = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
markerImage.image = '/system/themes/asp/img/gmarkerA.png';

var marker = new GMarker(
    new GLatLng(35.908236, -79.024531),
    {'title':'NC',
    'icon': markerImage
    });

// get info here
var markerIcon = marker.getIcon();
var anchorX = markerIcon.iconAnchor.x
var anchorY = markerIcon.iconAnchor.y
var iconHeight = markerIcon.iconSize.height
var iconWidth = markerIcon.iconSize.width


// v3 way #1
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(35.908236, -79.024531),
    'title':'NC',
    'icon': new google.maps.MarkerImage('/system/themes/asp/img/markerA.jpg'));

// v3 way #2
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(35.908236, -79.024531),
    'title':'NC',
    'icon': '/system/themes/asp/img/markerA.jpg');

// v3 way #3
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(35.908236, -79.024531),
    'title':'NC',
    'icon': { url : '/system/themes/asp/img/markerA.jpg'}
});


var markerIcon = marker.getIcon();
// how to get anchor position and size?????
```

Answer (score 2):

`icon.anchor` and `icon.size`

e.g.

```
var markerIcon = marker.getIcon();
var size = markerIcon.size;
```

This will probably require you to use the first method, rather than just specifying a URL string.
**NB: the MarkerImage object is deprecated, use Icon instead.**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(35.908236, -79.024531),
    'title':'NC',
    'icon': { url : '/system/themes/asp/img/markerA.jpg'}
});
```

Comment: If I create the marker that way then markerIcon only has a url property, but no size and anchor properties.  Also, developers may choose just to give a string for the icon property, not an object with a url property (such as example #2 above).  In that case getIcon() just returns a string, not an object.  So, unfortunately, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think api v3 allows you to get that info, unless you initially give it as a property.  I came up with this to give me some useful information.  Hope someone else finds it useful:

```
google.maps.Marker.prototype.getIconInfo = function() {
    var icon = this.getIcon();
    var size = null;
    var anchor = null;
    var image;
    var info;


    if (typeof icon == 'string')
    {
        image = new Image(); 
        image.src = icon;

        size = new google.maps.Size(image.width, image.height);
    }
    else
    {
        size = icon.size;   
        anchor = icon.anchor;   

        if (size == null)
        {
            image = new Image(); 
            image.src = icon.url;

            size = new google.maps.Size(image.width, image.height);

        }
    }

    if (anchor == null)
    {
        anchor = new google.maps.Point(Math.floor(size.width / 2 - 1), size.height);
    }

    var infoWindowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(anchor.x, 2);

    info =  {size:size, anchor:anchor, infoWindowAnchor:infoWindowAnchor};

    return info;
}
```